# Where do I write down the passive scores for skills?

Tags: dnd-4e

It tells me that my passive score for insight and perception are 10 + their checks, which are 0 because they are not yet trained. Where do I write down the passive scores?

I had it written in the misc. column first but then decided to write it in the character notes section. I have never played the game before and I started with the Red Box as it is often called.

Comment: I suspect this is D&D 4th Edition and have tagged it accordingly. If you think it is a different edition, please let us know. (If your red box contains [all this stuff](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/redbox.aspx) you definitely have D&D 4e)

Answer (score 10):

The official 4e character sheet from Wizards' website ([link](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/charactersheet)) has a section on the right side labeled "Senses" where you can put your passive Insight/Perception, and make notes of any special senses such as darkvision.

If you're playing Essentials, the sheets (one-page or two-page) have less information on them, and do not have a space for your passive values; however, since the passive values are simply your modifier plus 10, they are not overly hard to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for the Insight and Perception modifiers to be +0 you also need a Wisdom of 10 or 11 and to be level 1 (or level 2 or 3 with 8 or 9 Wisdom score)

But let's suppose it's really +0. You don't really need to write them down since it's so easy to calculate them: just add 10 to your skill modifiers and you have them.
My D&D 4e sheet has some space for them in the third column, under the *senses* header where the type of vision is also specified. I'm not familiar with the sheets you're using but My suggestion is to fill everything you find and if you find nowhere to write them, just decide where to write it (the notes section is a great place IMHO).

It could be useul to decide this place togheter with other players so that each one of you writes it in the same place, so when anybody forgets where it is the others will be able to tell him.
It's also worth noting how this value never gets rolled. It'd be better if your DM got a list of the passive insight and perception values instead of letting you keep them, since no real imput is needed from you when he must check against these fixed values.

On a separate note, the misc. column is intended for other bonuses to your skill, which end up making part of the passive skills total too. It's better if you use them for what they're meant for - you don't want to forget what that value is and add it to your active rolls next time you check your math.

Answer (score 1):

*In general*, unless you're the GM, **you** don't really need your passives. Your GM does, and probably should make themselves a form with that information to hand. Having it to hand makes it easier on the GM.

Given that the passives are the skill total +10, there's no need to write them separately. Just list the skill's value and remember to add 10 for passives. If there's a space on the sheet to hand, use it, but since you're asking, you don't have that sheet.

You may want to put them on a 3x5 index card, with your character's name, class, and level... and hand it to the GM at start of session.